# Inverse of a particular operator

Tags: operator-theory, inverse, differential-operators

I need help finding the inverse of the following operator. I am not sure about how to start. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Operator: $( I + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})$

Edit:

I actually need the inverse of this whole thing:

$\begin{bmatrix}  I + \beta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$.

I am assuming L2 space.

Comment: What space are you acting the operator on?  It is also likely to be unbounded.  If you are looking at $C^\infty$ functions on $[0,1]$ for example, the sequence of functions $\sin(nx)$ should give a sequence whose uniform norm is unbounded when applying the operator.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the domain and range of this function. If you mean the operator over the $C^\infty$ functions, note that it will not be invertible.  Taking for example $f(x) = \sin(x)$, we have
$$
\left(I + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right) f(x) = 0
$$
so your function is certainly not injective.

---

Suppose we are considering the operator over the space of functions with period $2$.  We define the inner product
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) \overline{g(x)}\,dx
$$
Then the family of functions
$$
a(x) = 1\\
b_n(x) = \sin(n \pi x)\\
c_n(x) = \cos(n \pi x)
$$
forms an orthonormal (Schauder) basis of this set.  Relative to the basis $\{a,b_1,c_1,b_2,c_2,\dots\}$, we can represent the operator $(I + \beta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})$ as 
$$
\pmatrix{1\\
&1-\pi^2\beta\\
&&1-\pi^2\beta\\
&&&1 - 2^2 \pi^2 \beta\\
&&&&1 - 2^2 \pi^2 \beta\\
&&&&&1 - 3^2 \pi^2 \beta\\
&&&&&& \ddots}
$$
We can find the inverse of this operator as we would find the inverse of any other diagonal operator.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have edited the question.

Comment: We have the same problem.  The operator
$$
\pmatrix{A\\&B}
$$
is only invertible if both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Comment: Why isn't $I + \beta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ invertible?

Comment: @T119 for the same reason.  Take $f(x) = \sin(\sqrt\beta x)$.

Comment: So? The operation gives $sin(\sqrt\beta x) - \beta sin(\sqrt\beta x)$.

Comment: @T119 No it doesn't; use the chain rule.  Anyway, I mean
$$
f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt \beta}\right)
$$
none of this should be particularly surprising to you

Comment: But in finite dimensions the determinant of this operator is not zero. Can a sequence of non singular operators converge to something singular?

Comment: @T119 yes; the set of invertible operators is not closed (it is open, though).

Comment: Perhaps you'd like an inverse of this function over the space of polynomials

Comment: I am working with C0 functions. But I still do not understand why you are saying it doesn't have an inverse. :(

Comment: The inverse of an operator $T$ is an operator $S$ satisfying
$$
TS = ST = I
$$
In this case, there can be no operator $S$ satisfying $ST = I$.

Comment: But what if take functions like $sin(n \pi x)$?

Comment: @T119 do you mean that the domain of your operator is the set of such functions?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Then depending on your choice of $\beta$, you might be okay.  Are you considering something like the set of periodic functions?  That might also be okay (again, depending on $\beta$).

Comment: Having these in order, can you suggest me a way to go about finding the inverse?

Comment: See my edit.   ${}$